# Self referencing record types in Standard ML

Tags: types, ml

I would to create a record type declaration such as

```
type 'a cx = { foo : string, handler : 'a cx -> 'a cx }
```

but this code does not compile.

I also tried "mutually recursive type synonym declarations", kinda

```
type 'a cx = { foo : string, handler : 'a hnd }
and 'a hnd = 'a cx -> 'a cx;
```

with no success.

In Haskell this would be

```
data Cx a = MkCx { foo :: String, handler :: Cx a -> Cx a }
```

How can I achieve that in SML?

### UPDATE

It is possible with mtually recursive datatypes

```
datatype 'a cx = MkCx of string * ('a hnd)
and 'a hnd = MkHnd of 'a cx -> 'a cx;
```

but it is ugly and there's no nice record syntax with unordered access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to your attempt would be:

```
datatype 'a cx = CX of { foo : string, handler : 'a hnd }
withtype 'a hnd = 'a cx -> 'a cx
```

However, this requires pattern matching to access the record. Defining accessor functions might make that more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Making an algebraic datatype with a single constructor works for me in SML/NJ, without needing to define multiple types:

```
datatype 'a cx = CX of { foo : string, handler : 'a cx -> 'a cx }
```

`type` doesn't work because it just defines an alias (like `typedef` in C), which cannot be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up packing separate types into the single module, i.e.

```
type 'a cx = { foo : string };
type 'a hnd = 'a cx -> 'a cx
signature CX = sig
    type t
    val cx : t cx
    val handler : t hnd
end
```